# New roots from old quadratic with coefficient p

Tags: roots

The roots of $−2x^2 + x + 4$ are $α$ and $β$. Suppose another quadratic, $px^2 + qx + r$, has roots $α +1/β$ and $β + 1/α$

What is the form of the new quadratic?

To solve this I got that $α+β=1/2$ and $αβ=-2$.

After doing so I end up with;

$q/p = -1/4$ and $r/p = -2$

However, Im not sure how to proceed and how to find out p? So I was wondering what I would do next.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $p(ax^2+bx+c)$ also has the same roots irrespective of the non-zero value of $p$. Hence, you can take any value of $p$ of your choice in your problem and the roots will remain same.

Comment: Does this mean that my p=1 q= -1/4 and r=-2?

Comment: Yes, any other choice of p may also work. Eg take p=4,q=-1,r=-8